# Meaning of Dollar Sign & Curly Braces Containing Javascript Block Outside of HTML Script Tag

Tags: javascript, html, templating, curly-braces, dollar-sign

I'm currently reading **'Javascript Web Applications' (O'Reilly, Alex MacCaw)** and very early on there's a code snippet which might appear to execute a JS function, within an HTML document, yet it is not enclosed by `<script>` tags:

```
// template.html
<div>
  <script>
    function doSomething(aParam) {
      /* do stuff ... */
    };
  </script>
  ${ doSomething(this.someX) }
</div>
```

Please could someone kindly explain the **dollar-sign-curly-brace notation**? I'm currently learning JS and I haven't seen this before, so I'm presuming it's either JS shorthand for code execution (if so, why no terminating semi-colon?), or perhaps some proprietary **templating** mark-up (Ruby? PHP?), or something else entirely?

Many thanks.

**UPDATE**

It transpires that later on in Chapter 5 (of the aforementioned book) we are then introduced to **Javascript templating**. It appears to be an assumption by the author that the reader has already encountered this templating technique before reading the book. As noted by **Stackoverflow member Esailija**, this book is ***not*** a beginners' guide to Javascript; I should add that I'm reading this book in parallel with **'Javascript: The Good Parts' (O'Reilly, Douglas Crockford)** amongst others.

*I had half-suspected some kind of templating, but I hadn't considered pure JS templating. I have used PHP and RoR frameworks in the past which also used similar templating concepts for injecting model data into views.*

One final point: my reason(s) for reading **'Javascript Web Applications'** is that it discusses the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern within the JS sphere. While it advocates the use of the **jQuery library** (among others) to both enhance and accelerate development, it is not a ***jQuery API book*** or yet-another-new-javascript-wrapper; rather, the book makes use of such libraries (where appropriate) to deal with cross-browser JS inconsistencies, while driving home actual JS best practices and patterns in creating 'web applications'.

Comment: It's wrong java script syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supposed to be javascript but a template file. Template file contains static html and very dumb presentation logic, usually in a pseudolanguage as it is in this case. It should not contain any real javascript - as it is said in the book that it's something you shouldn't do.

The book then goes into a refactored version that only has static html and the pseudolanguage statement. See [Javascript templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).

The book seems to be aimed at those who are already proficient at javascript and are looking into structuring their js better.

Comment: Esailija, thank you for your response. As you correctly assert, the book's example does indeed then provide a better version, again using the dollar/brace mark-up. Furthermore I now see that Chapter 5 (in that book) goes on to introduce JS templating.