# ${variable} usage without escaping string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a question for you today.

I was watching a talk about javaScript by Brendan Eich in which I saw a snippet of code along the lines of:

```
var food = 'a delicious potato';
console.log('I would really love ${food} for lunch.');
//outputs 'I would really love a delicious potato for lunch'
```

What interested me was the **${** food **}**. I had never seen this used or mentioned in JavaScript before and have since looked for usage examples to no avail. This seems it would be **incredibly** helpful to add in variables without having to first escape my strings (great for some of those tricky situations).

Is this a new feature of ES7 or something? If not are there any other cool little operating tricks I should know about? If it is, when can I expect to see this supported?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674711/meaning-of-dollar-sign-curly-braces-containing-javascript-block-outside-of-htm

A similar question.

Comment: Thanks, I did see that in a search before asking the question - however I get the feeling it may have been an unrelated and newly implemented feature of ES7 or something, just looking for further clarification :)

Comment: Looks like templating syntax. what was the talk?

Comment: There are a ton of libraries for this, pick which ever tickles your fancy.

Comment: Looks like a template string, which are defined in [ES6](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-template-literals)

Comment: It was on ES6 / ES7, I watched it a week or so ago. It just came to mind and there was a bunch of already existing functionality discussed as well.

Thanks Andreas - will look into it.

Comment: I think you speak of [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) that will be part of ES6

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was referring to [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) which will be a part of JavaScript ES6. Currently (March 2015) this works in Chrome 41 and Mozilla Firefox (gecko) 34. Below are excerpts from the link above.

Template strings are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them.

What you currently would have to write as:

```
console.log("string text line 1\n\
string text line 2");
// "string text line 1
// string text line 2"
```

With the use of multiline strings you can write as:

```
console.log(`string text line 1
string text line 2`);
// "string text line 1
// string text line 2"
```

The snippet I saw is a sort of combination:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and\nnot ${2 * a + b}.`);
// "Fifteen is 15 and
// not 20."
```

Thanks for the helpful comments.